# Дописать строки в начало файла на Python

Tags: python

Есть файл и строка.
Необходимо добавить строку в начало файла.
Нагуглил:

```
        with open(f'{fill_path}{n}.xml', 'rb+') as final:
        final.seek(0)
        final.writelines(['first_string'])
```

Но вот такой способ стирает часть строк начала файла.

Файлик хочу в формате xml, если что.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454298/prepend-a-line-to-an-existing-file-in-python

Comment: Нормальный способ только один - считать файл, добавить нужное куда нужно, записать целиком

Comment: @CrazyElf скажи это базам данных ;)

Comment: @eri Базы данных умеют писать в начало физических файлов любой кусок? ))

Comment: да не,  я к тому что прочитать в память 10 гигов а потом записать их в новый файл не всегда получается быстро! это всё зависит от операционной и файловой системы.

Comment: @eri Ну я сомневаюсь, что кому-то надо будет добавлять руками байты в начале 10Гб файла )))

Comment: ну мне часто нужно) напимер MBR заголовок прилепить к образу бакупа ФС

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно вставка в середину или в начало файла не работает просто так.

### Если файл маленький:

Прочитай его в переменную и перезапиши полностью.

```
with open(f'{fill_path}{n}.xml', 'rb') as final:
    data = final.read()
with open(f'{fill_path}{n}.xml', 'wb') as final:    
    final.writelines(['first_string'])
    final.write(data)
```

### Если файл в память не помещается:

Нужно вставить нули размером с вставляемый кусок через функцию [`fallocate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html), которой нет в Python - установите пакет, видел пару реализаций https://github.com/trbs/fallocate, https://github.com/junhe/pyfallocate .

Потом делаем seek на нужное место и  write.

На Windows не нахожу вставки такой.

Comment: Если файл большой, то надо делать слиянием в новый файл )

Comment: слияние это какой вызов?

Comment: Ну что сразу вызов. Просто прочитать, да записать в новый.

Comment: ну мало ли есть `c:\> merge f1.txt f2.txt` , concat не интересно)

Answer (score 1):

может как то так?

```
 with open('file.txt', 'r+') as file:
    content = file.read()  # Чтение
    file.seek(0, 0)  # Переход в начало файла
    file.write(new_line)  # Запись новой строки
    file.write(content)  # Запись старого содержимого
```